# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when I use google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, stack-overflow

I am trying to write simple example with google maps and markers but i faces with error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var map;
    var elevator;
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 1,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions);

    var markers = [];
    coords = [{
        lat: 55,
        lng: 37
    }];
    for (var x = 0; x < coords.length; x++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(x.lat, x.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });
        markers.push(marker);


    }

    fitBounds();

    function fitBounds() {
        var bounds = calculateBounds();
        if (bounds != undefined) {
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
    }

    function calculateBounds() {
        var allMarkers = markers;
        if (allMarkers.length > 0) {
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (i = 0; i < allMarkers.length; i++) {
                bounds.extend(allMarkers[i].getPosition());
            }
        }
        return bounds;
    }

});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P2QhE/2943/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` when calling `fitBounds` usually means you have called `bounds.extend` with an invalid `google.maps.LatLng` object.

This is incorrect (x.lat and x.lng are undefined):

```
for (var x = 0; x < coords.length; x++) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(x.lat, x.lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

It yields latlng with lat: NaN, lng: NaN

Which isn't valid.

should be:

```
for (var x = 0; x < coords.length; x++) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[x].lat, coords[x].lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/P2QhE/2949/)

**code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var map;
  var elevator;
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 1,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions);

  var markers = [];
  coords = [{
    lat: 55,
    lng: 37
  }];
  for (var x = 0; x < coords.length; x++) {


    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[x].lat, coords[x].lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);


  }

  fitBounds();

  function fitBounds() {
    var bounds = calculateBounds();
    if (bounds != undefined) {
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  }

  function calculateBounds() {
    var allMarkers = markers;
    if (allMarkers.length > 0) {
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      for (i = 0; i < allMarkers.length; i++) {
        bounds.extend(allMarkers[i].getPosition());
      }
    }
    return bounds;
  }

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```