# My google map returns " Maximum call stack size exceeded" error

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I am getting my lat and lan value from ajax. This is my sample code. Actually i am getting my lat and lan value from c# code.If i pass a value directly to javascrip it works fine. If i use via ajax it not working.  Any one know how to solve this.

```
var locations='';
$.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://www.ajax.com',
        async: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            locations = msg[0];
/*below result is what i am getting from ajax */
          //locations=["<a href='#' target='_blank'><b class='blue'>XXX</b></a>", 53.2279753, -1.6115431, 1], ["<a href='#' target='_blank'><b class='blue'>YYY</b></a>", 51.9935422, -1.7021487, 2] 


        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
locations = [locations];
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-39.92, 151.25),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;
        var markers = new Array();

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map
            });

            markers.push(marker);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));

        }

        //  Create a new viewpoint bound
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        //  Go through each...
        $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
            bounds.extend(marker.position);
        });
        //  Fit these bounds to the map
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        //AutoCenter();
```

Comment: [Maximum call stack size exceeded when I use google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866535/uncaught-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-when-i-use-google-maps)

Comment: 2 things, first maybe try Deserialization of the `locations` object, second the line `position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),` could passing strings into the `LatLng()` function which points back to my first point, try to convert the strings to decimals or floats, by a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

That can happen if the long/latitude is undefined or not a number. You might need to check that before creating the marker.

See the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17231733/1141089

Updated: Since your problem seems to be that you are passing strings to the marker function, you can solve it in two ways.

Either you solve it in javascript like this:

```
var value = parseFloat("55.2421410");
```

Or in your C# code(that's returning the JSON) like this:

```
var value = float.Parse("55.2421410", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```

So your Javascript code would look like this(if you choose to solve it with JS)

```
var latitude = parseFloat(locations[i][1])
var longitude = parseFloat(locations[i][2]);

//Do some error handling here, look for NaN, undefined etc.

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    map: map
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply my post. Actually javascript takes my value into string that is the real problem.How can i avoid this

Comment: You can parse a string to a float like this: `var value = parseFloat("55.2421410");`

But it would be better if you sent the correct type to your Javascript from the beginning(your c# code).